# Прошу помощи UMI.CMS Мультиязычность сайта

Tags: cms, tpl, umi, шаблоны

Здравствуйте.

Очень прошу помощи у знатоков TPL-шаблонов CMS UMI.
В шаблоне имеется вывод меню %content menu('main',1,'3')%
В администрировании сайта системы UMI подключил дополнительный язык eng, подключил к каждому TPL-шаблон.
С помощью добавления макроса %pre_lang% в шаблон пробовал изменить подключенное меню, но ничего не происходит. В чем ошибка не могу понять. 
Документацию UMI прочитал про мультиязычность. 
На форуме никаких подробностей не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

если вы имеете в виду именно перевод пунктов меню, то в шаблонах не нужно вносить. пункты меню собираются макросом из структуры сайта. копируйте структуры сайта в нужную языковую версию, затем переключаетесь в нее, в админке прямо, и редактируете через админку название страницы. %pre_lang% нужен только в ссылках. в них тоже могут быть макросы, но в "обычных" вызовах он не нужен

Comment: Так в том то и дело что через админку пытаюсь изменить название ссылки, не саму ссылку ЧПУ а название в меню.
Возможно ли то, что это второй вывод меню в шаблоне?
С основным главным меню у меня все в порядке изменяет. Его макрос %content menu('top',3)%

Comment: а вы точно не забываете переключиться в языковую версию?
можно у самих UMI.CMS спросить http://www.umi-cms.ru/support/
обычно быстро отвечают